# Uno Platform custom renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, uno-platform

Is is possible to create a custom renderer in Uno?
I need to create a native Android view and "embed" it in page or UserControl.

I didn't find any documentation about it.

We need to do the same as this example
https://github.com/UNIT-23/Xam-Android-Camera2-Sample

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's is no *renderers* in Uno: simply add your native control in the XAML and it should work unchanged.

### Example

There's a `NativeView` test in Uno [you can check here](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/master/src/Uno.UI.RuntimeTests/Tests/Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls/NativeViewPage/NativeView.cs), which is used [here in XAML](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/master/src/Uno.UI.RuntimeTests/Tests/Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls/NativeViewPage/NativeView_Page.xaml).

### XAML & Bindings

You can even set native properties directly in XAML, but bindings won't work on those.

If you need bindings, you can create a `DependencyProperty` and use the callback to set the native value.